# Is it possible to do Linux network namespaces (netns) on MacOS?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, linux-networking, docker, network-namespace

Context - I'm trying to get a docker cluster running on MacOSX.

Part of the install process for getting docker running is to install [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework/blob/master/pipework).

Pipework relies on `/var/run/netns`

My question is: **Is there an equivalent of netns for Mac OS X?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quote directly from the [Docker OS X page](http://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/)

> The Docker Engine uses Linux-specific kernel features, so to run it on OS X we need to use a lightweight virtual machine (vm). You use the OS X Docker client to control the virtualized Docker Engine to build, run, and manage Docker containers.

The rest of the page goes on to explain how to install docker on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Pipework must be run on the host it is setting an ip for, this is because it needs access to some of the cgroup/namespace files on the FS.

So, yeah you can't do remote pipework anyhow.